# phantomjs save array urls not working

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Okay so I'm using phantomjs to go through an array of urls that i want phantomjs to load and save each as an html file.

So far my code kinda works.
It starts loading each page and saving but after so many pages it just suddenly stops loading new pages and just saves the same one over and over again.
I believe its partially due to me not using page.close() but when I do the code doesn't work at all.

I was looking for someones help, especially for an explanation for whats the cause of the problem. And if someone has a solution for my problem it would be greatly appreciated. I know its messy at the moment, but I waiting to clean up after i discover the problem.

```
var fs = require('fs');

/* this is used get an array of urls I'm trying to find.
function linkfinder(){
var array =    fs.read('C:\\Users\\jacob\\Documents\\SDD\\links.txt').toString().split('\n');
console.log(array[1]);
console.log('ffff');
return array;
}*/

var urls = {
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1476,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1548,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1781,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1506,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1321,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1390,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1430,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1707,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1477,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1431,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1678,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1409,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1239,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1765,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=2203,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1889,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=2240,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1650,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1490,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1514,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1322,
http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1744
}

    var page = new WebPage();
    function handle_page(url){
    page.open(url, function(){
    //...
    page.injectJs('jquery.min.js');
    // var html = page.evaluate(function(){
        // return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
    // });
    //save to file
    page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    console.log("page load finished");
    var path ='C:\\Users\\jacob\\Documents\\SDD\\schools\\.html';
    var linked = url.substr(63, 4);
    var output = [path.slice(0, 37), linked, path.slice(37)].join('');
    console.log(output);
    //page.render('C:\Users\jacob\Documents\export.png');

    fs.write( output, page.content, 'w');

};

  // page.close();

    next_page();
});

}

function next_page(){
var url = links.shift();

if(!url){
    phantom.exit(0);
}
handle_page(url);
}

next_page();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but you need to specify the right path (i'm working on Linux, `/root/pjs` my path there).

```
var page = require('webpage').create(), fs = require('fs');

page.onLoadFinished = function() {}// won't work at all. The same content/every page((
var urls = [//an array
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1476",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1548",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1781",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1506",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1321",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1390",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1430",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1707",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1477",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1431",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1678",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1409",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1239",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1765",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=2203",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1889",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=2240",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1650",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1490",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1514",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1322",
"http://www.njcaa.org/member_colleges/college-profile?collegeId=1744"
]
var i=0;
function on_a_page(status){i++;
console.log("page load finished");
var output = '/root/pjs/'+page.url.substr(63, 4)+'.html';// You need to specify the right path (i'm working on Linux, '/root/pjs' my path there).
console.log(output);
fs.write( output, page.content, 'w');

if(i<urls.length){to_open()}else{phantom.exit()}
}
function to_open(){ page.open(urls[i], on_a_page);console.log(i) }
to_open()
```